# Stop animating GIF after one revolution

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimage

I am using the [uiimage-from-animated-gif](https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif) library to show an animated GIF through a `UIImage`. It's working, but I need to stop the animation or stop showing `imageView2` after one complete revolution.

I animate the GIF with the following code:

```
NSURL *url2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"dove-animate" withExtension:@"gif"];
self.imageView2.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url2]];
```

Comment: have you tried setting the `self.imageView2.animationRepeatCount`?

Comment: no change with imageview.animationrepeatcount

Comment: if you can get the gif image split up into multiple images, and put them into the UIImageView, then it will work, not sure if thats up to you though.. otherwise not sure sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you know the animation duration then you can just set a static image to your image view after that duration.

For example, if the duration is 2 seconds, then

```
[self performSelector:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0f];

-(void)stopAnimating{
    [self.imageView2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dove-animate.gif"]];
}
```

Comment: you forgot to add the method which calculates the duration of the GIF anim, without that it is just a half solution, because every GIF anim has _different_ duration.

Comment: I said if you know the animation duration then its work. Otherwise he have to edit UIImage+animatedGIF category static UIImage *animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFImageSource(CGImageSourceRef const source)  method with a timer or delegate

Comment: yep, that is true, but it it not really helpful, because the question is _how can you calculate the animation's duration?_. without it that is just a half-answer. as a theory it can be good, but it is just useless in practice.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to resort to gif's if you're storing the images in your bundle and not loading them from the web. You can actually have an entire folder of images (png's would be good quality and offer transparency). Then:

1. Load in each image into a `UIImage` via `UIImage + imageNamed:` or similar.
2. Create the `UIImageView` and set `animationImages` to your array.
3. Call `startAnimating` and `stopAnimating` on the image view as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Add timer to disappear the imageview. Then it appears like animation stopped

```
{
NSTimer *timer;

    timer =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 4
                                              target: self
                                            selector: @selector(removeAnimation)
                                            userInfo: nil
                                             repeats: NO];
}

-(void)removeAnimation
{
imageview.hidden=yes;
}
```